# vb.net automation to refresh Excel files with data from OLAP cubes

Tags: excel, vb.net, olap-cube

I am developing an exe procedure in VB.NET that processes several Excel files (with data from OLAP cubes) in a loop (processing all the Excel files located inside the same folder where the exe is):

- open file
- enable content
- write in 2 cells
- call RefreshAll (refresh data connections)
- save and close

**Normally it is working**, but with big Excel files (with a lot of CUBEVALUE formulas) I got random errors, probably because Excel is not responding.
I think the problem is not the RefreshAll call, cause my procedure has not the control back and it is waiting for it to finish, but in some files calculation mode is set with "Automatic", so as soon as the file is opened or after refreshall all formulas get calculated, but (before these calculations are done) my procedures gets the control back and I got an error when it tries to edit a cell or when it tries saving the file.

I tried to wait until calculation state = xlDone, but no success.

After data connections are refreshed, in the status bar I read this: CALCULATING PROCESSORS (2) or EXECUTING BACKGROUND QUERY

I also tried to set Manual Calculation mode, but the cells with formulas are not updated.

Do you have any suggestion?

```
Imports Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel
Imports Microsoft.Office.Interop
Imports System.IO


Public Class Form1

    Dim rootPath As String = System.Windows.Forms.Application.StartupPath

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    
        Dim di As New IO.DirectoryInfo(rootPath)
        Dim aryFi As IO.FileInfo() = di.GetFiles("*.xls*")
        Dim fi As IO.FileInfo
        Dim filename As String

        For Each fi In aryFi
            filename = fi.Name

            processaFile(filename)

            ' pulizia per non avere istanze di Excel aperte nel task manager
            GC.Collect()
            GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers()
            ' pulizia per non avere istanze di Excel aperte nel task manager
            GC.Collect()
            GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers()
        Next

        Me.Close()

    End Sub


    Private Sub processaFile(filenameX)
        Dim oExcel As Excel.Application
        Dim oBook As Excel.Workbook
        Dim oBooks As Excel.Workbooks
        Dim foglio As Excel.Worksheet
        Dim calculationType As Excel.XlCalculation

        oExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
        oExcel.Visible = True ' ''''''''''''False/True
        oBooks = oExcel.Workbooks

        oExcel.AutomationSecurity = Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoAutomationSecurity.msoAutomationSecurityLow ' abilita le macro

        oBook = oBooks.Open(rootPath & "\" & filenameX, UpdateLinks:=True, [ReadOnly]:=False, IgnoreReadOnlyRecommended:=True)

        oBook.Activate()

        oBook.EnableConnections()

        foglio = oBook.Worksheets("Sheetname")
        foglio.Range("C7").Value = "12"
        foglio.Range("C8").Value = "2020"


        oBook.RefreshAll()
        'oExcel.CalculateFullRebuild()
        'oExcel.Application.CalculateUntilAsyncQueriesDone()


        Do While oExcel.Application.CalculationState.ToString <> "xlDone"
            ' wait
        Loop

        'oBook.Close(SaveChanges:=True)
        oBook.Save()
        oBook.Close()
        oBook = Nothing

        oBooks.Close()
        oBooks = Nothing

        oExcel.Quit()
        oExcel = Nothing
    End Sub


End Class
```

Comment: Just to debug, did you try adding sleep at some places?

Comment: @ChristopherOezbek: thanks for reply, I will try and add some `Threading.Thread.Sleep(10000) `. Some file requires a lot of time to be refreshed/calculated (depending on users machine performances/db connections/...) and I should round this time interval up to an hour or more for these files, so as you said I can do it only in debug mode.